# How can I indirectly access a server that only allows connections from certain IP addresses?

Tags: windows-7, proxy, windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

I need to connect to a Windows Server 2003 machine at work from a Windows 7 machine at home via remote deskop.  The problem is, the server is set up so that only a very restricted range of IP addresses is allowed to connect to the server.  For a few weeks I will be unable to physically access the machine to change these settings, so I'm screwed unless I can somehow spoof my own IP address into one that the server allows.

I know this sounds shady and variations on this question have probably been asked a million times, but it's not like I need to break into this server.  I have full administrator rights to the machine, I just can't connect to the machine from outside the work network.

Is there any way to do this?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't spoof addresses with TCP. not without controlling the entire network infrastructure between you and the target machine. You will have to set up a proxy server/vpn of some sort.

Comment: I keep hearing about proxies, but I don't quite understand.  Does that mean the proxy server has to actually be present on the work network?

Comment: I actually can connect to the work network via VPN, but that seems to have no effect when I try to access the server in question with remote desktop, or even just ping.  What am I not understanding?  Am I somehow connected to the work network but not routing my local machine's internet traffic through it?

Comment: I actually can connect to the work network via VPN >> can you ping any other computer at your workplace..??